# Why does 3DES need private key to decrypt?

Tags: encryption, openssl, 3des, s-mime

I create two files, my.cer and my.pem ( include certificate and private key), I encrypt a file with my.cer, I use openssl smime -encrypt command. When decrypting data, it needs my.pem.

I think 3DES is symmetric cryptography so it should just need my.cer. Please explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, 3DES is a symmetric cipher and you use a secret key for both encryption and decryption with it. However, that is not the same thing as the keys used in RSA or other public key cryptography – you cannot (and should not) use either of them for 3DES.

Since you are using [S/MIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S/MIME), you are actually using public key encryption. Any reference to 3DES is about the symmetric part of a [hybric cryptosystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem). That is, you use the public key encrypt/generate a secret key that encrypts the actual message. So you need the private key to decrypt it.

Comment: they did that because its harder to encrypt larger files with asymmetric wasn't it?

Comment: @blacklight, yes, that is basically the reason for hybrid cryptosystems in the case of RSA.